# Sending SMS using PHP

Tags: php, sms

It's become necessary for the application to alert user through SMS. Not contry specific.

- Need to send SMS anywhere in the world.
- How to send it using PHP

I have to pay, I know that I'm ready though.

- I have no idea to choose **SMS gateway server**.

Please refer me some SMS gateway servers (good service) to rely on. Thank you.

Comment: this is not a programming question

Comment: Yeah. But programmers only knows about it. That's why I choose to ask here.

Comment: Choose an SMS gateway/service (this is *not* a programming question), then read and follow the documentation said gateway/service provides. I would initially rule out using providers without sufficient documentation or support to help *you* use *their* product.

Answer (score 1):

you can opt for textmagic . http://www.textmagic.com/ lot of options email to sms, sms to email .. and lot more ...

Comment: Good gateway but not suitable for India. It will not reach DND activated customers.